# Saving empty data frame to parquet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem saving empty table as parquet. In this case the schema is not preserved and the table cannot be read afterwards.

```
myDF.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("part_id").save("aa")
```

My SQL queries are relying on the same set of tables, and in a case of a table that is empty and therefor cannot be read the queries do not work. 
Is it any way to save the empty table with metadata ?

With best regards, 
Michael

Comment: Seems to work just fine. Could you provide a reproducible example including information about Spark version?

Comment: Are you able to load the metadata afterwards? I am using spark 1.5.0. I can try this with 1.5.1....

Comment: Looks like it. Are you sure your types are OK? It is possible to get null type columns which are not correctly serialized / deserialized.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I have found the problem. I have removed partitionBy call, and afterwards it was working just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed partitionBy call and after this the metadata was saved correctly